# How to display symbol characters for Python?

Tags: python

I've been trying to figure this out my own, but I couldn't come up with solutions for this. I did come across to `SpecialSym["$", "@", "#"]` but I wasn't able to work that one into this code.

```
         print("Password is incorrect, please try again...")
passW()
```

Comment: are you interested in other special characters? e.g. !@#$%^&*()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding the condition which would check whether any of the characters is in the list ["$", "@", "#"] or not.
The updated code would be:

```
import re #regular expression

print("Please enter a password to log in...")

def passW():
   while True:
      password=input("Enter a password:\n")
      if password=="Y0urC0llege":
         print("Logging in...")
         print("Your login was successful.")
         print("Welcome, Professor.")
         break
      elif len(password) < 10:
         print("Please make sure your password is as least 10 characters long.")
      elif re.search("[0-9]", password) is None:
         print("Please contain as least 1 number in your password.")
      elif re.search("[A-Z]", password) is None:
         print("Please contain 1 capital letter in your password")
      elif re.search("[$@#]", password) is None:
         print("Please contain as least 1 character symbol in your password.")
      else:
         print("Password is incorrect, please try again...")
passW()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can add any other character inside that list, if you consider it "special" too.

Comment: I know this isn't related to the question, and I'm kind of on a deadline with this but do you know what I am doing wrong with the break statement in this code? I put ; after the break code which helped, however every time I don't put in the correct answer, it ends without re-asking me to enter the password.

Comment: I am updating the answer as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take special characters in a variable after that you can check the condition like below:

> ```
> SpecialSym = ['!','@','#'] # You can add as many symbols you want.
> elif not any(char in SpecialSym for char in password):
>      print("Please contain as least 1 character symbol in your password.")
> ```